# Как бинарно сериализировать папку и файлы в ней

Tags: c#, .net, serialize

Я нашел немного кода, но мне никак не выходит сериализировать, а потом десериализировать GetDirectoriesR(dir).ToArray(). В конечном итоге код должен сериализировать и десериализировать папки и их вложения.

```
 public class Forms
    {
        [Serializable]
        class Directory
        {
            public Directory[] SubFolders { get; set; }
            public File[] Files { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        [Serializable]
        class File
        {
            public byte[] Data { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        private IEnumerable<Directory> GetDirectoriesR(string root)
        {
            foreach (var dir in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(root))
            {
                var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
                var directory = new Directory
                {
                    Name = dirInfo.Name,
                    Files = GetFilesR(dir).ToArray(),
                    SubFolders = GetDirectoriesR(dir).ToArray()
                };
                yield return directory;
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<File> GetFilesR(string dir)
        {
            foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                var fInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                yield return new File
                {
                    Data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file),
                    Name = fInfo.Name
                };
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Не надо было искать немного кода, надо было делать самому.

Comment: @AGS17  Да это явно поможет

Comment: [BinaryFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx). Дополнительно данные можно [сжать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: То есть вы хотите сериализовать _содержимое_ файлов?

Comment: @ VladD Понимаю что выглядит не корректно но все же. Мне нужно сериализовать папки и файлы в них. При этом должно сохранится иерархия, то есть должно выглядит так же как и до сериализации.

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдёт не сериализация, а создание архива из каталога? Если нет -- вам нужно придумывать свой собственный формат, как хранить данные и готовых решений тут нет. Да и задача какая-то не шибко практичная, ей-ей. Код который вы нашли -- так себе, а расходы по оперативке слишком велики для того, чтобы крупную директорию в лоб "засериализовать".